# Do Klingons not bathe or not like to take baths?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, klingon

In TNG episode "Conspiracy":

> TROI: Data, it's just not the same. Have you ever been for a real
>   moonlight swim?
>
> DATA: One can swim in moonlight?
>
> TROI: How about you, Mister Worf?
>
> WORF: Swimming is too much like bathing.

Also in TNG episode "Cost of Living" Worf looks miserable in the mud baths but I just assumed it was mud baths but not baths in general.

Is it just Worf or do all Klingons hate baths? If it's all Klingons do they not bathe at all? Is that dialogue from the "Conspiracy" episode enough to deduce that Worf does not like baths or not bathe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67683/does-worf-stink

Comment: @Dreamwalker I'm not asking about Worf. Also I'm asking for a contrast between Worf and other Klingons. I'm not sure if conspiracy is the only mention or conclusive proof of Worfs feelings about bathing, but body odor is not exactly what I'm asking about here.

Comment: Hence why I said possible and didn't mark it as duplicate.  I was just bringing it to your attention.

Comment: @Dreamwalker I appreciate it. I was just letting you know I read it and it didn't really give me what I was looking for.

Comment: “Worf looks miserable in the mud baths but I just assumed it was mud baths but not baths in general” — I think it’s *Worf* in general.

Comment: That is why there are no words in Klingon for "Eau de Cologne".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Marc Okrand, in his excellent "[Klingon for the Galactic Traveler](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9Vz1q4p87GgC&pg=PT79&lpg=PT79&dq=%22though+once+restricted+to+this+form+of+food+preparation%22&source=bl&ots=foDwAdiZ4x&sig=n-JC3kzg1ZVow7Hh1MtS5Qoxvvk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid_8Kp2tDPAhVDKMAKHar4B0oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22though%20once%20restricted%20to%20this%20form%20of%20food%20preparation%22&f=false)", describes bathing (in the sense of submersion in water) as an "occasional undertaking" and one that is largely avoided. This suggests that most Klingons agree with Worf.

> The verb {HaH}, though once restricted to this form of food preparation, is now often used in the more general sense of "soak, drench". It is frequently heard in the reflexive form ({HaH'egh} "soak oneself") in reference to such activities as drinking a great deal, which has positive connotations, and **bathing, an occasional undertaking with negative connotations**

It's also worth noting that the only other Klingon that we spend any length of time with (Torres) also strongly favours sonic showers over water ones.

Comment: It's possible that Klingons have an instinctive dislike of water. But then, it could just be a social thing with Torres being a coincidence.

Comment: @pointlessspike - Plus she's only half- Klingon. I only mentioned her for completeness sake and because it's really the only other TV-canon example I've come across.

Comment: @Valorum - another bathing example: in part one of TNG Season 6 "The Birthright" - Worf comes across a Klingon bathing in a river / pond. Although - she turns out to be half-Romulan and almost entirely removed from Klingon culture so it's tough to cite that as a definitive either

Comment: Of course this doesn't imply that they have poor personal hygiene. Maybe they clean themselves some other way. Most of Star Fleet seems to prefer a sonic shower to bathing, for example.

Comment: @user  -Apparently he has a distinctive odour; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67683/does-worf-stink