# Can Klingons swim?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, klingon

The question ‘[Do Klingons not bathe or not like to take baths?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89758/do-klingons-not-bathe-or-not-like-to-take-baths)’ got me thinking about whether a Klingon could swim. It looks like they hate water, but if thrown into a life-threatening situation, are they able to swim to save themselves? Or would they just sink like a rock?

In any of the Star Trek universes, is there an example of a Klingon swimming?

EDIT: Another reason I am wondering about their swimming ability is the fact that Klingons are very strong, much stronger than humans. That would mean that their muscle density is way higher than a human's, which should mean that they would not float as easily as a human would.

Comment: Doesn't Worf "swim" in ST:Generations after the plank is "removed"?

Comment: @JonClements, I have no idea?

Comment: Well - he does but it was on a holodeck so... Not sure if it counts... But looked like swimming...

Comment: @JonClements, if he is swimming make it an answer. Cheers

Comment: I'm on mobile - I'll let someone post that with some YouTube or something ;-)

Comment: @JonClements Of course, Worf is maybe not the best example given that he was raised by human parents.

Comment: Wow, I totally read [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67683/4650) as "Does Worf Sink?" but it's, "stink"

Comment: Your muscle density concept assumes that klingon and human anatomy and biochemistry is identical.

Comment: The stronger -> muscle density -> swimming assumption is inaccurate even here on earth.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In TNG:Firstborn, K'mtar suggests Alexander Rozhenko (who is in 3/4 a Klingon), that he should try going swimming in the lake near his uncle's (Kurn's) house. [From Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/273.htm):

> **K'MTAR:** Have you ever been to the Homeworld?
>   **ALEXANDER:** No.
>   **K'MTAR:** I think you would like it there. At your uncle's house there is a lake
>   you can swim in that is so clear you can see all the way to the
>   bottom.
>   **ALEXANDER:** Really?
>   **K'MTAR:** You have cousins there. They want
>   to meet you.

This is the only reference found at https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Swim

Edit:
 In "**DS9:Let He Who Is Without Sin**", Dax and Worf have a conversation about taking a bathing suit and going swimming in the lagoon:

> DAX: But it is my mistake to make. Now why don't you go up to our room
>   and put on your bathing suit so we can swim in the lagoon.
>   WORF: As you wish.

and:

> DAX: So what do we do now?
>   WORF: Now we watch the suns set.
>   DAX: I have a better idea. Why don't we go swimming.
>   WORF: I didn't bring a bathing suit.
>   DAX: I won't tell if you don't.

One can easily see that Worf does not oppose going swimming, however it may be possible it's because of Jadzia's assets... :)

Comment: And in Generations; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfF4Jq478_s although this appears to be more *not drowning*.

Comment: @Valorum, good find!

Comment: @Valorum - I agree, the clip does not show any swimming, just preventing from drowning :)

Comment: I rather suspect that her goal is to have sex with him in the water. That merely requires paddling (presumably above waist-height) rather than actual swimming.

Comment: @Valorum and, given what I've heard of Klingons, it seems that even if it were more dangerous to swim due to muscle mass, that increases the likelihood of them doing it.

Comment: @EdmundDantes He is easily treading water, after being somewhat unexpectedly dropped into the ocean, in clothing not exactly suited to it.  I think that is fairly clear evidence that Klingons, at a minimum, are capable of learning to swim

Comment: there's also a swimming Klingon (well...half Klingon / half Romulan) in The TNG episode "Birthright"

Answer (score 25):

In *Star Trek: Generations* during a Holodeck adventure when Worf is promoted,  he is given the challenge of retrieving his hat that is suspended high above an outstretched plank.

Riker comments:

> He won't make it no one ever has.

However, Worf is indeed successful. Riker then proceeds to have the computer remove the plank. This causes Worf to fall into the water.

We see a now upset Worf treading water, and not struggling, so he is able to swim!

Starts at about 2:30 in the below clip.

Comment: Since the safeties are on, it's reasonable to assume that the holodeck would allow even the least capable swimmer to tread water and not drown. That's not the same as swimming.

Comment: @Valorum But I am sure the holodeck could not control Worf's body movements... knowing how to tread water versus actively drowning are not the same thing either ;-)

Comment: No, but since it can play with apparent gravity, each flail of the arms could be much much more effective than in reality.

Comment: @Valorum Alright, I concede, its just a funny scene and shows a Klingon in water....

Comment: That wile e coyote moment...

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of the good evidence on Klingons swimming - they're humanoids, made mostly of water, with some flesh and bones. There's no reason to believe their buoyancy would be significantly different than that of humans; and their musculo-skeletal system is about the same. So, yeah,  for sure they can swim.

Of course, if said Klingons are clad in heavy metal armor, that's a whole other matter...

Comment: Problem is that they were much, much stringer than humans, which could mean they were much more dence body weight wise.

Comment: And all the redundant internal organs can also affect their average body density.

Comment: @KyloRen: Their being stronger means nothing unless they're made of metal or some weird elements instead of organic compounds.

Comment: @EdmundDantes: Redudant = copy or similar to the original = same density.

Comment: This seems very speculative.

Comment: More muscle density for more strength.

Comment: @KyloRen: "Muscle density" means how much muscle relative to fat etc. That still doesn't make them unorganic, or changes the fact they're mostly water.

Comment: No, muscle density means means the muscle is far more densely packed with muscle fibers , which increases its weight without increasing its size.

Comment: @einpoklum having redundant organs does not mean the same mass overall. Same mass per organ but there is now *2 of them.

Comment: @user001: Extra mass is not a problem, we were talking buoyancy.

Comment: @KyloRen: These increases in density are not significant compared to the effect of water and air cavities on the body's density.

Comment: @einpoklum Mammalian skeletal muscle has a [specific gravity of 1.06](http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/56/5/B191.full#R23), so if Klingon muscles are like Human ones, more muscle means less buoyancy.

Comment: @Robert: 1.06 is very similar to 1... you would need a huge increase in relative muscle mass to make a humanoid sink. A person has, on average, a gravity of [0.98](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_swimming), where the majority of the mass is already muscle. But if you add more muscle mass, you would need larger lungs too, meaning you scale the gravity-near-zero air bubble which AFAIK contributes significantly to buoyancy

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, air is buoyant.

Comment: A fat person floats a lot more easily than a muscular person. My mom, somewhat fat, used to float with no issue, while I, not too fat (at the time), had to actively paddle to stay afloat. I'm sure a Klingon warrior would easily have the strength to swim for a while, but it's entirely possible they wouldn't float without paddling, which would make long-distance swimming, or staying alive after a shipwreck, more difficult.

Comment: @einpoklum and buoyancy is related to density so extra "mass" is of course a problem. D=M/V, basic physics. Humans are only "buoyant" when lungs are full, due to extra low density volume. Barely buoyant at that. It would not matter how much supposed extra lung capacity they have, they breathe out and its harder to float.