# Does Data *smell*?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Throughout Star Trek, Data reminds people that he is, in fact, an android. While he doesn't sweat, his artificial skin and hair should have their own scent -- yet it's never remarked on, as far as I know.

Does Data have a particular scent?

[image: Data]

<sub>(Sorry, [Soong](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126854/does-data-smell)!)</sub>

Comment: He probably smelled like something after he walked across the bottom of that lake in Star Trek 9.

Comment: Terrible! No, wait...

Comment: The woman from "Thine Own Self" takes a whiff of Data's breath and reports nothing. Perhaps the android's skin has no smell (nothing perceptible to humanoids, at least). Surely his clothes have some sort of smell, but that wouldn't be Data's smell, of course.

Comment: I think this is the natural progression from my question!

Comment: The title is ambiguous as it could mean to ask whether Data has an olfactory sense. Would "Does Data have an odor?" be a better phrasing?

Comment: @JimConant yes it would, but it wouldn't sound as good 

Comment: @JimConant It was posted shortly after "Does Data smell?" was asked. It's a fun title!

Comment: @Axelrod: Ah, well that gives important context. Maybe the OP ought to link to that question.

Comment: @JimConant I *am* the OP, and the link has been there all along.

Comment: @Axelrod: Aha, it was not a clear reference to another question so I didn't click that.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67683/4918 "Does Worf stink?"

Comment: That question has nothing to do with this one.

Comment: And this now has more votes than the original!

Comment: For the same question in the Questionable Content webcomic universe, see http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3146 and http://www.questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=3167 which tell that Bubbles can smell.

Comment: @JimConant That's what I came here to note! Because I'm easily amused I thought of does he stink (because I'm unsure I have ever seen a reference to someone or something 'smelling' in this context without meaning to smell bad or < good) but I also thought at the same time that maybe the question was asking if he had a sense of smell.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit that conflicts with intent of the title.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Main canon

His *breath* has no smell, presumably the rest of him is much the same.

> **TALUR:** *Hmmmm. Remarkable set of teeth. no sign of decay.* (sniffs) *Breath smells like.* (puzzled) *Well, it doesn't have any
> smell, actually.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Thine own Self](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/268.txt)</sup></sub>

### EU Novels

Data has a scent, but it's not one that's especially noticeable.

> He bore no scent save that of a freshly laundered garment and **a hint
> of bioplast sheeting.** Nonetheless, he looked uncannily human, down to
> the pores of his skin.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek TNG: The Buried Age](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Buried_Age)</sup></sub>

### Reality

All of the Enterprise crew (including Brent Spiner) [absolutely reeked of body odour and cleaning fluid](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3022935/how-star-trek-killed-something-worse-than-klingons-spandex), at least for the first couple of seasons. The spandex fabric they used for the uniforms resisted cleaning except with harsh chemicals that could only be used once or twice a month. For the rest of the time, the cast were expected to sweat into their suits which would be spot-cleaned.

> "Spandex retains odor, so there is a certain part where if you’re
> wearing them for a long period of time, you can’t really clean all the
> smell out, and it becomes a little bit annoying. And it also retains
> the odor of the dry cleaning fluid. It is, on a day-to-day basis,
> unpleasant."
>
> <sub><sup>Bob Blackman, the costume designer behind the show’s iconic uniforms</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice! Add a (potentially funny) picture. Do it quickly and I'll give you half a crown!

Comment: As a comment on the "Reality" section, from another large sci-fi franchise: Someone who worked on *Doctor Who* in the '80s (or was it the '70s?) once told me the insides of Daleks smelled horrible.

Comment: It would be nice if this quote was attributed here.   Yes, I can go find it in the linked article, but this answer just left me confused as to who is being quoted.   (Also, what if the link breaks?)

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Go crazy.

Comment: I have an unfortunately acute sense of smell.  Especially with his level of activity, Data would have a unique smell.  The spandex would have been unbearable, except that if I had been on set anything would have been worth it!