# Was the problem of human odor ever mentioned in Star Trek before?

Tags: star-trek

I recently started watching *Star Trek: Enterprise,* and a prominent issue raised by T'Pol and other Vulcans—namely, the monks in "The Andorian Incident"—was human odor. One of the monks at the temple said that "the smell must be unbearable," and T'Pol was reportedly given a "nasal numbing agent," and did not eat human food.

I have not watched as much *Star Trek* as others might have, but was this problem *ever* mentioned before? And if it was, was it considered as serious a problem as described in *Enterprise,* a series that comes after most of the others, even if it was set before them?

Comment: The answers at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126946/4918 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126854/4918 "Does Data smell?" don't seem to answer this.

Comment: In Star Trek V The Final Frontier they were interrupted while on their camping trip and back on the Enterprise in the turbo lift Kirk says he could use a shower. Spock looks at Kirk and says, "Yes".

Comment: Well, we know that Neelix reeks, and Worf probably smells to high heaven, too.

Comment: @HamSandwich where is it said that Neelix reeks?

Comment: @HamSandwich Also yes, Worf’s odour is mentioned in DS9 (at least, possibly TNG too) and Klingon’s odour in general is discussed in VOY.

Comment: @dean1957 True, but other humans could have said that and smelled Kirk.

Comment: @Darren In the first episode of Voyager, it's revealed that Neelix is a dirtbag that hates to shower.

Comment: @Darren: To my recollection, the only discussion of Worf's odor in DS9 was in "Trials and Tribble-ations." One person complaining about it was not actually talking about Worf's odor (he just talked about "smelly klingons" in general - also, *he* was a klingon in disguise), and the other two were O'Brien and Bashir, who were obviously just messing with him.

Comment: @HamSandwich, As I recall, Neelix was running low on water, so he couldn't bathe.  Later in the episode he had  made a deal with Voyager and was bathing with gusto.

Comment: I believe I was a little down that day, which explains my comment. I don't really think Neelix is a dirtbag. Worf, on the other hand, probably stinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Voyager "Distant Origin" (S3 E23), two Voth scientists are on Voyager, cloaked.  One mentions something about the smell, and the other says "they are mammals" dismissively (or, perhaps, just accepting that as part of field work).

So in the sense that human odor has been mentioned before, the strict answer is "yes".

Comment: But Klingons and Vulcans also have odor, and if they dismissed it so quickly, it means that they probably didn't need a nasal numbing agent.